# RVIZ visualize the data in the different plane. How to fix that?

Tags: ros, rviz, tf2, robot-state-publisher, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have set up an environment in gazebo with Kinect sensor. Sensor position and the joint is fine.

But I visualize the `pointcloud` data in Rviz it is showing in XZ plane instead of XY plane. Take a look at the following image

[image: image description].

In the image above, it is capturing the image from the front in gazebo but showing on the top of the robot in Rviz.

I tried to put the static transform between frames.
`<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="kinect_frame" args="0 0 0 -1.58 0 -1.58  /middle_link /kinect_link 100" />`
But its conflicting with the transform published by `robot_state_publisher`.

```
<link name="kinect_link">
    <inertial>
      <mass value="0.1"/>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <!--The 3x3 rotational inertia matrix. -->
       <inertia ixx="0.0000282916666667" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.0000282916666667" iyz="0" izz="0.00005625"/>
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
            <mesh filename="package://simbha_model/urdf/meshes/kinect.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
        </geometry>
      <material name="Black"/>
    </visual>
        <collision>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="0.065" radius="0.005"/>
      </geometry>
   <material name="Black"/>
    </collision>
  </link>
<joint name="kinect_link_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="middle_link"/>
    <child link="kinect_link"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.075 0.0 0.155"/>
  </joint>
```

How to set the kinect frame???

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/292906/rviz-visualize-the-data-in-the-different-plane.-how-to-fix-that?/) by [simbha](https://answers.ros.org/users/29493/simbha/) on ROS Answers with karma: 241 on 2018-06-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2018-06-11**:
Try setting the rpy (roll pitch yaw) of the kinect_link_joint in your urdf.

**Comment by [simbha](https://answers.ros.org/users/29493/simbha/) on 2018-06-12**:
I tried but that changed view(other than front) also. even in gazebo model, the same issue is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Finally, I Solved the problem by myself. I created a dummy link on which Kinect plugin was attached and then in the launch file use `robot_sttae_publisher` and `static_tranform` between dummy link and kinect_link.
I changed the `static transform` in such a way it solved my issue

```
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="kinect_frame" args="0 0 0 -1.58 0 -1.58 /kinect_link /kinect_tf_link 100" />
```

Here `kinect_link` is the dummy link and `kinect_tf_link` is the link on which Kinect plugin is attached

---

Originally posted by [simbha](https://answers.ros.org/users/29493/simbha/) with karma: 241 on 2018-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1